# How to hide Azure DevOps Board and Repos to specific Group?

Tags: azure-devops

i have various groups of users in my Azure DevOps, Each team has separate boards, i want to hide those boards and repos to each other. So that they cannot know other team's board and repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create areas and then assign those areas to the appropriate teams in Project and Team Configuration, respectively. When you create a Work Item, you assign it to a specific area and only the team configured for this area will have access to it.

as for the repos, go to project settings, repositories and disable inheritence, remove all default groups and add only those you wish to grant access.

Answer (score 1):

The board and items will still be visible, but it won't be in "My boards". You can prevent a group or person to see items by setting up Security on a Area (in Project configuration). But the name of the board will still be visible in the drop down, but it will seem empty.

Answer (score 0):

Almost a year later and this is still the case. I just can't get my head around the fact that stakeholders that are only allowed access to one specific Area are able to see the names of all other Area's they don't have access to.

Just is just poorly designed, if you ask me.

I've played with groups and permissions so long now, I can honestly say there is no reason inaccessible Areas should be visible to stakeholders in the Backlog and Sprint directories.